# Layout getOutput() return different if cache enabled or disabled

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, template

UPDATE :

it actually return the right value as long as the "Layouts cache" is disabled, but when I enable it the output is becomes incorrect.

---

I have this very simple piece of code which is supposed to return html code
(located in my controller):

```
<?php
protected function _refreshDdateHtml(){
        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $update = $layout->getUpdate();
        $update->load('checkout_onepage_refreshddate');
        $layout->generateXml();
        $layout->generateBlocks();
        $output = $layout->getOutput();
        return $output;
    }
```

<strike>However, the value of $output is not the same depending on the server where I run the code.</strike>
**However, the value of $output is not the same depending on if the layout cache is enabled or disabled.**

I tried to find the source of the issue without result. Both the database and the file system can be different from one server to the other, but I can't know for sure where.

Here are more details:

Controller class definition:

```
class Something_Deliverydate_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
```

The handle in the layout file:

```
<checkout_onepage_refreshddate>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_deliverydate" name="root" output="toHtml" template="deliverydate/checkout/onepage/refreshddate.phtml" />
</checkout_onepage_refreshddate>
```

The loaded handles seem to be the same on both servers though as this line give the same result:

```
var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```

<strike>Do you have an idea why the template called is different from one server to the other ?</strike>
Do you have any idea why the output is changing depending on the cache status, even if the cache folder is empty ?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: if you have different code bases and databases check whether in the one where you are not seeing the expected result the **extension** has been **properly installed**, the **cache** has been **cleaned** and the **compilation** (if active) has been **refreshed**.

What's more, activate **logging** in `System > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer > Log settings` and check whether there are any **errors** in `{magento_install_directory}/var/log/system.log` and/or in `{magento_install_directory}/var/log/exception.log`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't try before but the responsible for this difference in the output is the status of the layout cache: if enabled, it doesn't work. 
I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: You say the cache folder is empty: unless you have alternative cache systems configured (redis, memcache) that folder shouldn't be empty with cache enabled; it can be a symptom of the fact that `{magento_install_directory}/var/cache` is not writable; in this case Magento stores cache under the `/tmp` folder of the system (assuming you are on a *nix system).

Comment: Sorry I meant the problem occurs even after I empty the cache manually (when then, the cache folder is empty). It's getting filled without problem too.